# If $n$ is an integer , find all the possible values for $(8n+6,6n+3)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have got 2 questions which I could not solve:

1) if $n$ is an integer , find all the possible values for $(8n+6,6n+3)$

2)if $n$ is an integer, find all possible values of $(2n^2+3n+5,n^2+n+1)$

Comment: Any thoughts?  An easy thing to do is to write out the values for the first few $n$, see if that generates any ideas.

Comment: When I first read the question, I thought the parentheses were representing ordered pairs, but the answers are talking about gcd. Are the parentheses supposed to represent gcd? Ideal generated by these elements? I think the notation needs to be clearer.

Comment: @Acccumulation Haha yes I thiught the same thing "How epse can you possibly simplify this sequence in $R^2???$"

Comment: I'm voting to close for lack of context.  It is possible the OP (or someone motivated to help) could clarify the Question to better conform to the answers provided (or in the OP's case, what really made the Question important, difficult, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Let $d=\gcd(8n+6,6n+3)$, then $$d\mid 8n+6$$

$$d\mid 6n+3$$

so $$d\mid 6(8n+6)-8(6n+3)= 12$$

so $d\in \{1,2,3,4,6,12\}$ Since $6n+3$ is odd $d$ can not be $2,4,6$ or $12$ so $d=1$ or $d=3$ (which is realised at $n=3k$ for some integer $k$)

---

For second one:

Let $d=\gcd(2n^2+3n+5,n^2 + n+1)$, then $$d\mid 2n^2+3n+5$$

$$d\mid n^2+n+1$$

so $$d\mid 2n^2+3n+5-2(n^2 + n+1) =n+3$$

then $$d\mid (n^2+n+1)-(n^2-9)-(n+3)=7$$

So $d=1$ which is ok or $d=7$ which is realised if $n=7k+4$.

Comment: Should be $8n+6$ and you can multiply by $3$ and $-4$ rather than $6$ and $-8$, but good method all the same

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ A euclidean sequence is $\ \overbrace{8n\!+\!6,\,6n\!+\!3,\,2n\!+\!3,\,{-}\color{#c00}6}^{\Large  a_{k-1} -\, j\ a_k\ =\ a_{k+1}}\,$ so the gcd is

$$(2n\!+\!3,\,\color{#c00}{2\cdot 3}) = (2n\!+\!3,\color{#c00}2)(2n\!+\!3,\color{#c00}3) = (3,2)(2n,3) = (n,3)\qquad\qquad $$

$(2)$ A euclidean  sequence is $\ 2n^2\!+\!3n\!+\!5,\!\!\!\!\underbrace{n^2\!+\!n\!+\!1,\, n\!+\!3,\, \color{#0a0}7}_{\large f(n)\ \equiv\ \color{#0a0}{f(-3)}\,\pmod{\!n+3}}\!\!\!\!$ so the gcd $= (n\!+\!3,7)$